# I want to pass variable to AntD Breadcrumbs route in react

Tags: reactjs, antd, breadcrumbs

I want to pass a variable to the following the AndtD breadcrumbs route.

```
<Breadcrumb
            routes={[
                { breadcrumbName: BREADCRUMBS.REPORTS },
                { breadcrumbName: BREADCRUMBS.NEW_REPORT },
            ]}
        />
```

I want to do something like this

```
<Breadcrumb
            routes={[
                { breadcrumbName: BREADCRUMBS.REPORTS },
                { breadcrumbName: BREADCRUMBS.${breadcrumb} },
            ]}
        />
```

Comment: What is BREADCRUMBS?  This is part of you application not Antd, and breadcrumb accepts : interface Route {
  path: string;
  breadcrumbName: string;
  children: Array<{
    path: string;
    breadcrumbName: string;
  }>;
}

Comment: Can you provide a replica on codespan ?

Comment: Change BREADCRUMBS.${breadcrumb} for BREADCRUMBS[breadcrumb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was worked for me

```
<Breadcrumb
        routes={[
            { breadcrumbName: BREADCRUMBS.REPORTS },
            { breadcrumbName: BREADCRUMBS[breadcrumb] },
        ]}
 />
```